# NHibernate - CreateSQLQuery exception "No persister for ..", why?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create a SQL query in NHibernate using CreateSQLQuery:

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(
    "select loss.id as loss.Id, loss.start_date as loss.Date, " + 
    "       (select ... limit 1) as loss.Reserve, " +
    "       (select sum(m.val) ...) as loss.Payment " +
    "from LossData loss .. where ...";

// Commenting or uncommenting these doesn't have any effect either
query.AddScalar("Id", NHibernateUtil.Int32);
query.AddScalar("Date", NHibernateUtil.DateTime);
query.AddScalar("Reserve", NHibernateUtil.Double);
query.AddScalar("Payment", NHibernateUtil.Double);

query.AddEntity("loss", typeof(LossQueryDto));
query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(LossQueryDto)));

var list = query.List<LossQueryDto>();
```

But it gives me an error "No persister for: 'LossQueryDto'". What's wrong with this query ? 
Do I need an additional mapping for the query ? If so, can I define one in Fluent Nhibernate ? I'm using NHibernate 3.1.

The Dto itself is like this:

```
public class LossQueryDto
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual double Reserve { get; set; }
    public virtual double Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the mappings?

Comment: What mappings ? I don't have any mappings for the 'LossQueryDto'. It was my understanding that mappings are not required if using CreateSQLQuery (when not doing named queries). If I need to create a mapping, then how do I do it and how to I call the query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not querying entities, but DTO, so you can remove following:

```
query.AddEntity("loss", typeof(LossQueryDto));
```

Comment: Turns out I did need a mapping for the dto. As you are the only answerer, I accept your answer though it's not entirely relavant.